# Como mover o titulo de uma coluna para outra?? (web scraping-python)

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando fazer um web scraping, porém se você visualizar o site percebe que certos títulos estão sobre certas colunas. O que meu programa faz é pegar a tabela, criar duas colunas cheias de NaN e atribuir a elas um título de coluna da primeira coluna efetiva do site. O que pode estar errado??? Parece que ele pula 2 colunas, preeenche com os dados e só depois inicia da forma certa.

Preciso que o primeiro titulo va para a terceira coluna, o segundo para a quarta, o terceiro para quinta e assim por diante.

Como deveria ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import pandas as pd
import lxml
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

url = "https://www.sunoresearch.com.br/acoes/itsa4/"

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ng-select/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ng-select/div/ul/li[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ng-select/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ng-select/div/ul/li[4]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]').click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="demonstratives"]/div[3]/div[2]')
html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(name='table')

df_full = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(df_full)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mano, recomendaria você dar drop nessas colunas, pois como essa df_full é um data frame pandas você pode usar o comando,

```
df_full = df_full.drop(labels = ["Descrição", "1T2020"], axis = 1])
```

Ai seguindo esse raciocínio de nome da coluna antiga (old_column_name) para nome da coluna nova (new_column_name), como no exemplo abaixo,

```
df.rename({"old_column_name1":"new_column_name1","old_column_name2":"new_column_name2"}).
```

Isso se o problema for somente renomear as colunas.